# Making text disappear and reapear

Tags: html, css

On my navigation bar I have a logo, I want this logo to disappear at 1080px. Currently I am using

```
@media (min-width: 1080px){
    .navlogo a{display: none;}
}
```

And this works, but at 425px I want the logo to reappear. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: @media (max-width: 425px){
    .navlogo a{display: block;}
}

Comment: please check my fiddle and let me know if its good for you. Hope i got you right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this media query for display logo

```
@media (max-width: 425px){
    .navlogo a{display: block;}
}
```

Check [fiddle for 600px](https://jsfiddle.net/LeoLion/yhmpfLhx/1/)

Check [fiddle for 1080px](https://jsfiddle.net/LeoLion/yhmpfLhx/1/)

See [image: Here]

Also see here for [image: updated point]

Comment: he wants the logo to reappear @ 425px and disappear @ 1087 so you might wanna correct the code..

Comment: @DhavalChheda from 425 to below, logo will appear and above that logo will disappear.. right?

Comment: i don't think his question meant that..he needs to be a little more clear but that was my interpretation of his question

Comment: @DhavalChheda i think we should leave this on OP.. :)

Comment: No its not reappearing

Comment: I have used text but if you are using img in your code then you have to change css according to that.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough, but I need the text to be displayed as none at 1080px, which is working, but the problem comes that I need it to be displayed again at 425px, which is not working

Comment: @bvdo Can please explain me what do you want exactly, you want to reappear your logo between 425 to 1079 or what??

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
@media ( min-width : 425px) {
        .navlogo a{
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }

    @media (min-width : 1080px) {
        .navlogo a{
            opacity: 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: why opacity?? when we can use display?

Comment: I usually use opacity hence provided that answer and frankly never used display:none..

Comment: Suggestion, try to use display:none rather then opacity as opacity is for blur but not to hide. Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Thanx for the advise Leo , will keep that it mind..thanx for takingn the time out for writing the suggestion..

Comment: My pleasure.. have a nice day :)